# change excel file extension when submitting form

Tags: excel, xlsx, vba

I have a form for users to submit a request for small moves, adds, changes etc.

It has worked brilliantly for me for the last couple of years but now any external customers cannot use it because our corporate mail blocks .xlsm extensions.

Clearly I need to use .xlsm to create the file but I need to change it to a .xlsx for the purposes of mailing it to me.

THe code I am currently using is below. Can anyone help me modify it to change the extension to .xlsx?

`Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_3()`

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim Site As String
Dim ChangeType As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Requestor As String
Dim implementationDate As String
Dim notice As String


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

Site = Range("d21").Text
ChangeType = Range("D11").Text
Requestor = Range("d13")
implementationDate = Range("n10")
notice = DateDiff("d", Now, implementationDate)

TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = "SMAC Request " & "Logged on " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(wb1.Name, Len(wb1.Name) - InStrRev(wb1.Name, ".", , 1)))
wb1.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr)
```

I tried using the following line to change it but it throws an error saying Excel cannot open the file because the file format or extension is not valid, verify that the extension matches the format of the file.

`'FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51`

All help appreciated

Comment: If you save it as `.xlsx` then you are removing all VBA from the file. Try `.xls` instead. Alternatively, you can also save it with an invalid extension (for example `.xly`) and say in the email that they should change it.

Answer (score 0):

The `SaveAs` method, unlike the `SaveCopyAs` method has an optional parameter for `FileFormat` (see [this](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac020.htm) for a discussion). The following sub, which you can perhaps modify for your purposes, will, when run from a `.xlsm` file save a macro-free copy of the file with the same name (but with `.xlsx` instead of `.xlsm`) in the same directory as the file that contains the macro. It doesn't delete the `.xlsm` file -- though you might want to make sure that any work is saved before running this:

```
Sub StripMacros()
    Dim fname As String
    fname = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    fname = Replace(fname, ".xlsm", ".xlsx")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```